# How should I refresh multiple tables when a trigger is activated in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, triggers

I have a very long geographic algorithm what computes a lot of columns from source columns. Although a lot of columns are computed from source columns (source columns are in the beginning of the algorithm), some column in the beginning of the algorithm and columns in the middle of the algorithm can be updated by workers so the algorithm parts (or algorithm subtree) should be recalculated from the newly inserted (measured by other workers, not computed or guesstimated data) referenced columns. The data is not just in one table, so sometimes it should recalculate other table values too.

My question is what is the best option for this?

I just need to write triggers for the columns what can be changed later? And, for example if trigger A in the beginning of the algorithm and trigger B in the middle of the algorithm, and if the worker changed the beginning, trigger A called and should be run until it changes the field what trigger B connected to? And will trigger B continue the refresh procedure? Do I think well about this?

Sorry if the question is not too accurate, but I have no experience about doing this and I haven't got any colleagues who can help me about advises. 
(and I found on forums you can't guarantee that triggers will be called from each other the right way, maybe will be called in bad order)

Answer (score 0):

So, to summon up: you have some business logic broken down in a few sections. Those sections produce intermediate results a user can override. And you need subsequent steps in you business logic to be retaken immediately when an user does override a intermediate result.

First off, triggers have various gotha's which make people steer away from triggers unless they absolutely have to. I.e.:

- A trigger is always captured in a transaction which makes it for example hard to log errors when something goes wrong
- Having considerable logic in a trigger will make your inserts and/or updates slow, besides the fact your application will need that into account chances are you'll hit deadlock problems.
- Sounds like your planning to have multiple triggers on single table, one to be fired on one set of fields an another fired on another set of fields. Unfortunately, this is not possible. Triggers are bound to a table. It might be wise to separate the generated data from user entered data into separate tables.
- Beware of triggers triggering other triggers, before you know it they're in a infinite loop.

**Edit:**
Not knowing your exact situation and requirement it's hardly possible to give advise on architectural decisions. As always, it depends. Only thing I can do is give pointers to take into account. And as I pointed out a trigger (any transaction) should take short as possible to complete. If you suspect it to take more than a second or two you might want to reconsider using triggers.

Once I've had a trigger running into trouble hitting deadlocks every once in a while. To resolve this, I've altered the trigger to insert the updated id's into a new table and have stored procedure process those ID's every 5 minutes triggered by a scheduled job.

The above worked fine for me, might or might not for you.

One extra little tip, apply [OO design paterns](http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html) to your SQL code. Unavoidable refactoring later on will be less painful.

Comment: I wanted to use triggers only because I believed it will be fast :D Because working with Arcpy for ArcGIS seemed to be too slow (running over 40-50 hours from beginning and not finished). So should I create a table where user can modify fields and it should initialize 1 trigger what refreshes other tables?

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to see a sample schema and scenarios - right now, it's hard to be precise.

However, using triggers for this kind of thing is usually a bad idea (okay, this is a personal opinion).

Triggers act as a side effect. Side effects are a bad thing when it comes to code - they're hard to debug, developers find it hard to think through all the scenarios, and it's easy to create never ending loops (insert trigger on table A fire, updates record in table B, update trigger on table B fires, inserts record in table A, insert trigger on table A fires, etc...).

Triggers are also quite hard to tune for performance. It sounds like you're doing a fairly complex set of calculations; making sure that the performance of the overall system is acceptable when using complex triggers is hard.

The scenario you describe, where multiple processes can cause the calculation to fire, with different triggers all working together, sounds like it could create dozens of different trigger sequences. Guaranteeing the logic in all those possible sequences sounds like it could be rather complex. Transaction management could lock

Instead, I'd recommend an asynchronous queuing system. Whenever an application changes a record, it pops a task on the queue, and an asynchronous process reads from the queue and runs whatever logic is required to update your data. This introduces a delay between posting the source data and updating the dependent tables, but it's much easier to debug, much easier to tune for performance, and far less likely to lock up your database.